# How to change BIOS hardware data from Ubuntu?

Tags: hardware, 21.10, motherboard

Today I came across [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Aqc_UpdCPqg) that changes the BIOS hardware data from Windows .
I want to change the name of the hardware that says A320MH to Z690GTA (random)

[image: Terminal Image]

How can I do this?

Comment: You want to intentionally misrepresent your motherboard to the OS? 

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. What is it exactly that you want to do, and for what purpose?

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem.

Comment: I want to misrepresent my motherboard model to my operating system. no purpose, only test...

Comment: English is not my mother tongue, I know 2 languages, sorry for the explanation, please help. WHY -1

Comment: BIOS are proprietary and only the manufacturer can reliably provide such a utility… all other methods up to now that rely on free/open source software are very risky and can render your system unusable and unable to boot at all … even on Windows… I strongly advise against this.

Comment: I'll take your advice into consideration Raffla. Thank you very much for the reply. I have spare motherboard i will do this just for test.